# Consume Serilog output from Class Library Static Method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, logging, serilog

I have two projects.

One is a class library (.NET standard 2.1) that is referenced from a nuget feed, and one is an API (.NET Core 3.1)

I would like all logs from the class library files to feed into the API logs. Currently my startup file for the API is configured as follows:

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()                .
            .WriteTo.Console()                .
            .CreateLogger();

        services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
        {
            loggingBuilder.AddSerilog();
        });
```

This works completely fine when injecting a logger into my Controllers.

```
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public UserController(ILogger<UserController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

I tried implementing the static logger as follows:

```
private static ILogger _logger => Log.ForContext(typeof(HelperClass));
Log.Information($"useful message");
_logger.LogInformation("useful message");
```

However no logging is appearing from my helper class static methods from the nuget class library project.

I have a feeling I need to connect the static Logger to the instance from the API somehow, but I'm quite lost at this point.

```
public static ILogger Logger { get; set; }
```

Any advice is much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: The question's title asks one thing but the question text asks something completely different. You don't need a static logger at all. You *inject* the `ILogger* instance to the classes that need it through their constructor. If you create those classes through DI, the logger is created by the DI container

Comment: `I would like all logs from the class library files to feed into the API logs.` make sure the *classes* have an `ILogger` dependency and pass an ILogger instance to them. You'll have to post your actual code if you want more help - how do you create those objects and where?

Comment: The API classes are injecting them but the class library static helper classes don't have constructors that take in (Ilogger) and I dont want to add them - that will transform it into instance classes

Comment: Don't use static classes then. Or pass the ILogger instance to the methods explicitly. Post your code. Microsoft.Extensions.Logging is built so there's no single static logger. If it demanded a static logger, every class would have to be built around it and using other logging frameworks like Serilog would be a *lot* harder

Comment: If you really-really want to, you can create a static property and assign an `ILogger` instance to it when you start your application.

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis. I realized this is a bit of an anti-pattern, but I really need the log output from that class library nuget package connected with my API logs.

Comment: That's what you wrote in the title. That's the exact opposite of what you ask in the question. `I really need the log output from that class library` that's what a sink does. It receives the output from Serilog and does something with it. What you wrote in the question though, is that you want to *log to ILogger* without actually injecting the interface. Only as a stop-gap until you fix that class library, you can save an ILogger instance (or even an ILoggerFactory) and call it from that class's methods. Which would require changing all of the methods of course

Comment: Are you asking something different though? Does your class library already use Serilog? In that case it already has access to `Log.Logger`

Comment: Yes the class library project (Client.Common) can use Log.Logger, but the logs do not show in the Api project when it is running.

Comment: This has nothing to do with what you asked then. You've already configured Serilog. `Log.Logger` is already set. This means the class library already sees it. For some reason (filters perhaps? log level?) those events get rejected. If you set the logger *again*, you end up with a new logger that has no sinks

Answer (score 0):

if you want use another log , like log4net, Nlog ....
ILogger will help you,  just injecting and get this like you done

```
public UserController(ILogger<UserController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

But if you sure to use only serilog .you can use static class by the way  are the same ( of course you need **using Serilog** at header of class code )

> Log.Information("log information");

Finally :
Using **Ilogger**  and Inject it to constructor class is the most standard and complete like a good student , lol